# Scipy output error :undefined symbol: sgegv_

Tags: python, scipy, theano, lapack, keras

When I tried running keras examples, the program output an error,

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/lapack.py in <module>()
    354 from .blas import find_best_blas_type as find_best_lapack_type
    355 
--> 356 from scipy.linalg import _flapack
    357 try:
    358     from scipy.linalg import _clapack

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_flapack.so: undefined symbol: sgegv_
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: what OS? How did you install scipy? Any errors during the installation?

Comment: Also, which BLAS are you using? Have you manually compiled/installed LAPACK?

Comment: @cel Ubuntu14.04. I tried using pip and binary code. No errors, but some warnings seems not important.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw Hi! That's latest BLAS and LAPACK manually compiled/installed.

Answer (score 3):

No need to downgrade your lapack. It is better to upgrade your scipy

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
```

Comment: **Do this.** Newer LAPACK is a good. Obsolete SciPy, however, is a bad.

Answer (score 2):

In lapack 3.6.0 some deprecated functions which are used in scipy were dropped.
You have to use lapack 3.5.0 or lower in order to get things to work back.